# Show weather info from observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to simply display weather details in my weather app, but I'm not able to access API response. This is what I tried so far:

[image: API response]

In my service.ts

```
 apiCall(): Observable<any> {
    const rec = new HttpRequest(
      'GET',
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=41,9109&lon=12'
    );
    return this.http.request(rec);
  }
```

In my component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.api.apiCall().subscribe((data) => {
      this.response = data.body;
      console.log(this.response)
    });
  }
```

In my html

```
      <div>
        <p>{{ response["current"]["humidity"] }}</p>
      </div>
```

It actually does show the info, but I have to reload the app to make it update, which is not the point of an observable.

Answer (score 3):

How often do you want it to update?  When you make an HttpRequest, that is a one-time request and will respond with data once.  If you want the page to automatically update, you will need to invoke an http request each time you want a new update (response).

You could use an rxjs timer observable and switchMap each emission to an http request to your api endpoint.  That should work.

### Edit

Something like this...

In your typescript:

```js
response$ = timer(10000).pipe(switchMap(_ => this._http.get(apiUrl))
```

In your html:

```html
{{response$ | async | json}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes.  https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: How jake say, http request is a one time call, then the problem isn't async pipe.

Comment: You right, 'response$ = timer(10000)' is nice. :)  Thats it